# Union of Two Measurable Sets is Measurable Using Diff. Def. of Measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Use property (ii) of theorem 11 as the primitive definition of a measurable set and prove that the union of two measurable sets is measurable. Then do the same for property (iv).
>
> (ii) There is a $G_{\delta}$ set $G$ containing $E$ for which $m^*(G-E)=0$.
>
> (iv) There is a $F_{\sigma}$ set $F$ contained in $E$ for which $m^*(E-F)=0$.

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are measurable. Then there exist $G_\delta$ sets $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that $A \subseteq G_1$ and $B \subseteq G_2$, and $m^*(G_1 - A) = 0 = m^*(G_2 -B)$. Using the distributive laws of intersections and unions, we can show that $G_1 \cup G_2$ is $G_\delta$ set, which must contain $A \cup B$. Moreover,

$$(G_1 \cup G_2) - (A \cup B)$$

$$= (G_1 - (A \cup B)) \cup (G_2 - (A \cup B))$$

$$= ((G_1 - A) \cap (G_1 - B)) \cup ((G_2 - A) \cap (G_2 - B)) \subseteq (G_1 - A) \cup (G_2 - B),$$

and by monotonicity we get

$$m^*((G_1 \cup G_2) - (A \cup B)) \le m^*((G_1 - A) \cup (G_2 - B)) \le m^*(G_1 - A) + m^*(G_2 - B) = 0$$

I believe the other proof is nearly identical: assume measurability of $A$ and $B$, and get the $F_{\sigma}$ sets $F_1$ and $F_1$; the union is a $F_{\sigma}$ set, and at this point we are essentially done. So how does this sound?

Comment: It sounds great.

Comment: It is really a nice proof .well done